# Final Route URL Change Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

I am working on a school project. while working on a schools detail page I am facing an issue with the URL. My client needs a clean URL to run AdWords. My school detail page URL: http://edlooker.com/schools/detail/4/Shiksha-Juniors-Ganapathy. But he needs it like http://edlooker.com/Shiksha-Juniors-Ganapathy. If anyone helps me out it will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: can u send me the url ???

Comment: Ya sure, http://edlooker.com/ this is the website URL, but the issue is with these type of URL's. http://edlooker.com/schools/detail/4/Shiksha-Juniors-Ganapathy

Comment: your route code ???

Comment: in my opinion the first url is as user friendly as i can be

Comment: You should disable debugging in production. In `.env` file change `APP_DEBUG=true` to `APP_DEBUG=false`

Comment: Route::get('/schools/{id}/{name?}',  function($id, $name)

Comment: @vigneshpbs, try out my answer. It will serve your purpose. Comment under the answer for any other details on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you will have to use one front controller for all requests and get data by [slugs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-slug), for example:

```
public function show($slug)
{
     $page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->first();
     ....
}
```

Your route could look like this:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'FrontController@show');
```

Comment: But how to use the url like he mentioned? According to your answer, we have to use `show` segment in url. Then it would catch the function and then we can use the `slug`

Comment: He'll need to keep a table with slugs and related information. It's a terrible architecture for any complex app, but if his teacher wants this, OP doesn't have a choice.

Comment: I meant to say, if this `show()` will be inside the front controller, then, to point our request to it, we need to use this word `show` in url. Then `show()` will return proper page according to the slug.

Comment: Looks like it's the project for the school (as client, which he does say).

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay you don't need to add `show` to the URL. The route will look like `Route::get('{slug}', 'FrontController@show');`

Comment: And he needs to add that to the bottom of `web.php` or it will override any route below it...

Comment: I implemented the same thing with my laravel 4.2 project but its not going to my controller function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define this route after all routes in your web.php (if laravel 5.x) or in routes.php (if it is laravel 4.2).

```
Route::get('{school}','YourController@getIndex');
```

And your controller should be having `getIndex` method like this,

```
public function getIndex($school_name)
{
  print_r($school_name);die;  // This is just to print on page,
  //otherwise you can write your logic or code to fetch school data and pass the data array to view from here.
}
```

This way, you don't need to use the database to get URL based on the URL segment and you can directly check for the school name in the database and after fetching the data from DB, you can pass it to the school details view. And it will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding) section in docs.

> **Customizing The Key Name**
>
> If you would like model binding to use a database column other than id when retrieving a given model class, you may override the getRouteKeyName method on the Eloquent model:

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```